# Как отключить переадрессацию на странице регистрации Вордпресс?

Tags: wordpress, регистрация

При переходе по ссылке https://www.promreg.ru/wp-login.php?action=register открывается страница https://www.promreg.ru/register. Если я правильно понимаю, где-то включен редирект, только вот не могу понять где именно.Я пробовал отключать некоторые плагины (Profile Builder, Admin Menu Editor), чистить .htaccess, а так же искал в functions.php. Как сделать что бы по ссылке открывалась стандартная форма регистрации Вордпресс? Все наверно проще чем кажется, но я чет не могу найти.

Сейчас на сайте активированы плагины:

- 3D FlipBook : Dflip Lite
- Admin Menu Editor
- Advanced Custom Fields PRO
  -Classic Editor
- Contact Form 7
- Content Views
- Disable Admin Notices Individuall
- Dynamic Widgets
- Fixed Widget
- Flexible Posts
- GTranslate
- List category posts
- List Custom Taxonomy Widget
- Loco Translate
- Login Logout Menu
- Menu Icons
- mqtranslate langcode widget selector
- Search & Filter
- Ultimate Category Excluder
- Webcraftic Cyr to Lat reloaded
- Widgets in Columns
- WordPress vertical Thumbnail Slider
- WP Google Search
- WP User Frontend
- Диспетчер файлов WP
- Сообщения, отправленные пользователем

Comment: 100% плагин для регистрации/управления юзерами

Comment: О.. всё не так и хуже чем описано в вопросе. По стандартной ссылке никуда не редиректит, а открывается страница защитой ХОСТЕРА. Это жесть..

Comment: Profile Builder? Я его отключил в первую очередь, но проблема осталась.

Comment: Нет, он не отключён. Его даже в коде видно.

Comment: ..Только нафига нужна стандартная голая страница. Эта же лучше.

Comment: Простоя его обратно включил

Comment: При переходе по ссылке открывается страница хостинга, но при повторной попытке идет редирект  https://www.promreg.ru/register

Comment: Можно было бы и эту форму оставить, но ее невозможно изменить и она вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: Непонятно чем вводит в заблуждение (те же поля что и в стандартной), но на 99,9% уверен, что форму можно изменить.

Comment: Через форму должна добавляться компания (как отдельный тип записи с последующим выводом на сайт), но по факту она просто регистрирует нового пользователя. Мне тоже казалось что форма должна редактироваться, но в плагине я не нашел таких настроек. Видео: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KByJVJkU0RE-aZ91Phn-n8vtcEG2sgHO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Кажется разобрался. Это плагин WP User Frontend перенаправляет на другую страницу. Спасибо за участие!